# Forcing deep transitive dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am using gradle version 4.X in my project. I want to force a transitive jar to a particular version. I followed [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version). But the problem here is that the jar version I want to force lies deep.

**Example:**

Below is the *build.gradle* file

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:1.5.21'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.0'
}
```

The problem here is that 'spring-boot-starter-jersey:1.5.21' uses 'logback-classic:1.1.11'. Now the force command should work so that it upgrades to logback version-1.2.0. Problem comes here,

logback-classic is not a direct dependent of spring boot jersey. The dependency tree looks like below.

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey -> 1.5.21.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.21.RELEASE
          +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.21.RELEASE
              +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11 (*)
```

How can this be achieved in gradle?

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file (or an example?)

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question with specific use case

Comment: Your existing build.gradle file does what you want already. You could also just add an explicit direct dependency to ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.0: the highest version wins. What exactly is the problem? Why do you think what you have doesn't work?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes I can directly compile 'logaback:1.2.0' and that will win, but that is not what I want. This configuration.all is not working dude, since there are more interdependent jar between jersey and logback. I don't know why this is not working. My project is a multi project directory structure.

Comment: I just tested it, fixing your jersey starter version to 1.5.21.RELEASE, and of course putting the configurations.all instructions outside of the dependencies block, and it works fine. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: When using Spring Boot, it overrides the correct behaviour that Gradle offers with some incorrect behaviour that gives a massive headache. The documentation is here but be prepared to rip any remaining hair out. https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/

In particular, it just doesn't work correctly if you have some dependencies as `compileOnly` and others as `compile` for example.